# Visualizing weights of convolutional layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, data-visualization, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to visualize the weights of the first layer (conv2d) of the Inception (v2) model I'm training from scratch as a learning exercise. My goal is to see something like this:

[image]

After training for 48 hours, my weights are looking like this:

[image]

I realize that the model has not converged yet, but I'm under the impression that I'm not saving those images correctly. What is the proper way to save those weights as an image? This is what one of the 7x7 filters look like:

```
[[[-0.05254178 -0.32257697 -1.12509501]
[-0.0577225   0.05430533  0.36126333]
  [-0.60956329 -1.30094147 -0.94367725]
  [ 0.54475862 -0.59896839  0.15690225]
  [-0.97573054  1.32717788 -1.60333276]
  [ 0.15729432  0.75963998 -1.15895975]
  [ 0.44433147 -0.59633678  0.85462248]]

 [[-1.25177848 -0.22818488  0.59435815]
  [-0.33860862 -0.57336748 -0.98618352]
  [ 0.72633511 -1.13217747 -1.76324153]
  [ 0.51535034 -1.67747593  0.65356445]
  [-0.35212585  0.30183136 -0.56150651]
  [-0.76186991  0.82538754 -0.97745162]
  [-0.59434128  0.83723128  0.87456381]]

 [[ 1.45617723 -0.76524097 -0.86497647]
 [-1.26491678  0.17541747  1.15705132]
  [-1.08001506  0.85055047  0.85818022]
  [ 0.74638301  0.62615412  0.82004201]
  [-0.18160205 -1.20272303 -0.83150953]
  [ 0.10087592 -0.81851184 -0.42592993]
  [-0.55882829 -0.17606784  0.18895631]]

 [[ 0.3052578  -0.96171474 -1.50700831]
 [ 1.42404032  0.76130313 -0.76801056]
  [ 1.17354596 -0.95108169 -1.26256537]
  [-0.31658572 -1.77376604  0.51870042]
  [-1.15100074 -0.10693484  1.1963098 ]
  [-0.71053046 -0.0048219   0.04927144]
  [-0.54291326  0.53240746  0.07321835]]

 [[ 1.30089164 -0.80944502 -0.73323363]
 [-0.23359792  1.8435204   0.40987673]
  [-1.03293586 -0.47056404  1.50919926]
  [ 0.16482946 -0.70123744 -0.1847167 ]
  [ 0.8541984  -0.65718001 -0.72896409]
  [-0.35303     1.07880664 -0.47393021]
  [ 0.31868654 -0.32843634 -0.1771179 ]]

 [[ 0.51924646 -0.17256238  0.36290699]
  [ 1.49726737 -1.06288946  0.0867526 ]
  [-0.0572592   1.11176336  1.13637185]
  [-1.85817802 -0.77071941 -1.24363136]
  [ 1.39292431  0.80537623 -0.74663389]
  [ 0.78745258 -0.12404614  0.52013248]
  [-0.63301861 -0.09680288 -0.75839919]]

 [[ 0.53743452  0.40094584  1.37857044]
  [-1.42719209 -0.21600421  0.66738045]
  [-0.91122359  1.03506982  0.3147507 ]
  [-1.41389787  0.44936335 -0.55145448]
  [-1.85846198  0.33287755  0.19934106]
  [ 0.51051307 -0.62650138  0.7086826 ]
  [ 0.05585323  0.07293719 -1.15675306]]]
```

And here's how I'm saving them:

```
# Get weights from the model
weights = estimator.get_variable_value('Conv2d_1a_7x7/weights')

for index in range(64):
  plt.imsave('weights-{}.png'.format(path, index), weights[:, :, :, index])
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think that you are doing something wrong with the images? The examples that you show seem to be larger than 7x7, so maybe they originate from some higher-level layer in the model?

Comment: There are many articles and lectures that I've seen that mention that one of the ways to tell that a conv network has converged is by looking at the weights of the first convolutional layer. Here's an example: http://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn In my case, I have only been training Inception v2 on a single CPU for 48 hours. However, my expectation is that by now I should be seeing some smoothness in those filters. Maybe this is a sign that I still have some training to do?